# Unable to draw the background video behind the segmented image and foreground video top of the image in Canvas

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, mediapipe

I am trying to draw 1 video from the back of the image and another video on the top of the image. I'm using mediapipe task vision to segment the image and after that trying to upload videos one background and one foreground video. I intend to create a canvas with a segmented image and with foreground and background video. I tried different ways but was unable to do so. Always get the error `Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.` and Canvas only shows the segmented image. Please check my code and help me to figure out the issue. **legendColors** is an array of colors.

```
const ImageSegmentation = () => {
  const [imageSegmenter, setImageSegmenter] = useState(null);
  const [canvasClick, setCanvasClick] = useState(null);
  const [foregroundVideo, setForegroundVideo] = useState(null);
  const [backgroundVideo, setBackgroundVideo] = useState(null);

  const foregroundRef = useRef(null);
  const backgroundRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initImageSegmenter = async () => {
      const audio = await FilesetResolver.forVisionTasks(
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/tasks-vision@0.10.2/wasm"
      );
      const segmenter = await ImageSegmenter.createFromOptions(audio, {
        baseOptions: {
          modelAssetPath:
            "https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-models/image_segmenter/deeplab_v3/float32/1/deeplab_v3.tflite",
          delegate: "GPU",
        },
        runningMode: "IMAGE",
        outputCategoryMask: true,
        outputConfidenceMasks: false,
      });
      setImageSegmenter(segmenter);
    };

    initImageSegmenter();
  }, [foregroundVideo, backgroundVideo]);

  const handleBackgroundVideoChange = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      video.width = 640;
      video.height = 360;
      video.controls = true;
      video.autoPlay = true;

      // Append video to the body or another container
      document.body.appendChild(video);

      // Set ref for background video
      backgroundRef.current = video;
    }
  };

  const handleForegroundVideoChange = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      video.width = 640;
      video.height = 360;
      video.controls = true;
      video.autoPlay = true;
      // Append video to the body or another container
      document.body.appendChild(video);

      // Set ref for foreground video
      foregroundRef.current = video;
    }
  };

  const handleImageClick = async (event) => {
    if (!imageSegmenter) return;

    const canvas = canvasClick;
    if (!canvas) return;

    const input = event.target;
    const file = input.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = async (e) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = e.target.result;

        img.onload = async () => {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;
          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          input.value = ""; // Clear the file input

          // Wait for both segmentation and video loading to complete
          await Promise.all([segmentImage(img)]);
        };
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

  const segmentImage = async (img) => {
    const result = imageSegmenter.segment(img);
    handleSegmentationResult(result, img);
  };

  const handleSegmentationResult = (result, img) => {
    console.log("Handling segmentation result");
    if (!canvasClick) return;

    const ctx = canvasClick.getContext("2d");
    const { width, height } = result.categoryMask;
    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

    // Handle the segmentation result as needed
    const mask = result.categoryMask.getAsUint8Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {
      const legendColor = legendColors[mask[i] % legendColors.length];
      imageData.data[i * 4] = (legendColor[0] + imageData.data[i * 4]) / 2;
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 1] =
        (legendColor[1] + imageData.data[i * 4 + 1]) / 2;
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 2] =
        (legendColor[2] + imageData.data[i * 4 + 2]) / 2;
      imageData.data[i * 4 + 3] =
        (legendColor[3] + imageData.data[i * 4 + 3]) / 2;
    }

    // Draw the image data on the canvas
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Draw the background video behind the segmented image and foreground video top of the
    // Draw the background video
    
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundRef.current, 0, 0, canvasClick.width, canvasClick.height);

    // Apply the segmentation mask to the background video
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    // ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Reset the globalCompositeOperation
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

    // Draw the foreground video on top of the segmented background
  
    ctx.drawImage(foregroundRef.current, 0, 0, canvasClick.width, canvasClick.height);
  
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Segmenting images using the MediaPipe Image Segmentation Task</h1>
      <section id="demos" className="invisible">
        <div className="segmentOnClick">
          <canvas
            ref={(canvas) => {
              if (canvas) {
                setCanvasClick(canvas);
              }
            }}
          ></canvas>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageClick} />
          <div>
            {/* Add file input for foreground video */}
            <input
              type="file"
              accept="video/*"
              onChange={handleForegroundVideoChange}
            />

            {/* Add file input for background video */}
            <input
              type="file"
              accept="video/*"
              onChange={handleBackgroundVideoChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```